# How do I scan comma-delimited strings from text files into separate structure members in C?

Tags: c, string, macos, csv

I've run into a road block on a program.  I declared a structure student with the fields id, first_name, last_name, email, gender, and grade.  Then I declared an array of structures, struct student record[10000].  I then wrote code to count the number of lines in the CSV file.  Then I read the first line of the file as a string "header_row."

I then attempted to fscanf the id field into the structure array member record[0].id.  This part worked fine.  The next part is where I got stuck.  I wrote:

```
    fscanf(fp, "%s", record[0].first_name);
```

and the fscanf command considered all of the commas in the rest of the line to be part of the string, and so it scanned the following into record[0].first_name:

,Martin,Welch,mwelch0@ehow.com,Male,80

How do I fscanf for strings that are separated by commas, and how do I tell C that the commas are not part of the strings, but rather that the commas are delimiters?

The code that I wrote is as follows:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    struct student
    {
        int id;
        char first_name[20];
        char last_name[20];
        char email[50];
        char gender[6];
        int grade;
    };

    int main()
    {
        FILE *fp;
        int count_lines = 0;
        char chr, header_row[44];
        struct student record[10000];

        fp = fopen("/Users/tenorjas/Documents/USF courses/EEL 2161 C programming/exampledata.csv","r");

        // extract character from file and store in chr
        chr = getc(fp);

        while (chr != EOF)
        {
            // Count whenever new line is encountered
            if (chr == '\n')
            {
                count_lines = count_lines + 1;
            }

            // Get next character from file
            chr = getc(fp);
        }

        printf("There are %i lines in file exampledata.csv\n", count_lines);

        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); // go back to beginning of file

        fgets(header_row, 44, fp); // read the header row of the file
        printf("%s\n", header_row); // display the header row

        fscanf(fp, "%i", &record[0].id);
        printf("%i\n", record[0].id);
        fscanf(fp, "%s", record[0].first_name);
        printf("%s\n", record[0].first_name);
        fclose(fp); // close file

        return 0;
    }
```

The output I got from that code is as follows:

There are 1001 lines in file exampledata.csv
id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,grades
1
,Martin,Welch,mwelch0@ehow.com,Male,80
Program ended with exit code: 0

What I want to happen is this:
"1" ends up in the "id" field
"Martin" ends up in the "first_name" field
"Welch" ends up in the "last_name" field
"mwelch0@ehow.com" ends up in the "email" field
"Male" ends up in the "gender" field
"80" ends up in the "grade" field

Comment: Sidenote: `fscanf` is a function, not a statement.

Comment: Please have a look at `strtok` function. Use `fgets` to read from file.

Comment: Aside: `char chr` should be `int chr`, the type returned by `getc()`.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, especially xing - that did the trick.